# About finding a strictly positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can we find a strictly positive integer $d$ such that

$$a=\dfrac{12d}{d-12}$$
   $$ b= \dfrac{13d}{d-12}$$
    $$r=\dfrac{5d}{18}$$
   $$ w= \dfrac{13d}{12}$$ 
    $$c= \dfrac{10d}{3(d-12)}$$

are all strictly positive integers. I trying some values. However I cannot find any solution.

Comment: Where did you get this Q?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: this is a self study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $r$ and $w$ are integers, then $\operatorname{lcm}(12,18) = 36$ is a divisor of $d$. If $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $b - a = \frac{d}{d-12}$ is an integer, so $d-12$ divides $d$. For every strictly positive multiple $d$ of $36$ we have $\frac{d}{2} < d-12 < d$, so $d-12$ is not a divisor of $d$.